# How can I see everything authorized to use my Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id, privacy, authorization

Does Apple only provide you with information about what devices are currently signed into your Apple ID account?  Is it possible and how can I see all devices, computers, Home Sharing, Audible websites, AirPlay devices, Sharing, and all the other **things that have ever been authorized** to use my Apple ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you login to www.icloud.com with your AppleID you can go to Settings and look under "My Devices" to see all systems (Phones, iPads, Macs) authorized and logged in to that account.

This will also allow you to sign out of any other browsers signed into your account.

I am not aware of any way to see any information on what particular computer is logged into your account via iTunes (PC or Mac) but you can "De-authorize" those computers all at once. That can be done from iTunes that is currently signed into your account.

Comment: The key word that Im wondering about is ( currently). That word suggests that you do not get to have the information about who what when where has the authorization. What has authorization to our Apple IDs not what is currently signed into our account. I want to know that.

Comment: You may need to contact Apple Customer Support.